# Issues with AJAX grabbing and saving records

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a form to database save/grab using ajax/jquery.  I am having issues saving and grabbing though.  My ajax keeps failing and I can't tell why.  I know this should work.  I movedmy ajaxCall to its own function to call it on load and on submit and that is when things seemed to go south.  Can someone point me in the right direction on what is wrong.  I have my jquery and php below.

**JQUERY/AJAX CODE**

$(document).ready(function() {
    ajaxCall();

```
$('#submitBtn').on('click',function(event) {
    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    event.preventDefault();
    ajaxCall(formData);
}); //END OF .ON

function ajaxCall(formData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/save.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        //dataType: "string",
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        success: successCall,
        error: errorCall
    });
} //END OF AJAX CALL FUNCTION

function errorCall() {
    alert("There was an error with this request!")
}// END OF ERROR CALL FUNCTION

function successCall(data) {
    //var records = $.parseJSON();
    var record = "";
    console.log(data);

    /*$.each(data, function() {
        ID = this['ID'];
        NAME = this['NAME'];
        PHONE = this['PHONE'];
        ADDRESS = this['ADDRESS'];
        var html = "<tr><td>" + ID + "</td><td>" + NAME + "</td><td>" + PHONE + "</td><td>" + ADDRESS + "</td></tr>";
        $(html).appendTo("table");
    });*/

    //var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data);   
    //alert("ajax call complete");
} //END OF SUCCESS CALL FUNCTION
```

}); //END OF .READY

**PHP CODE**

```
class dbClass {


    private $host = "localhost";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $schema = "formtest";
    public $dbCon;

    function __construct() {

        $this->dbCon = new mysqli($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->schema);
        if ($this->dbCon->connect_error) {
            die("Issue Connecting: " . $dbCon->connect_errorno . "Error: " . $dbCon->connect_error);
        }
        //var_dump($dbCon);

    }
    function saveDBRecord($dbName, $dbPhone, $dbAddress) {
        //HOW TO FIGURE THIS OUT
        $query = $this->dbCon->prepare("INSERT INTO contact (contact_name,contact_phone,contact_address) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $query->bind_param("sss",$dbName,$dbPhone,$dbAddress);
        //var_dump($query);
        $query->Execute();

        $recordData = $this->grabRecords();
        return $recordData;
    }

    function grabRecords() {
        $query = $this->dbCon->query("SELECT * FROM contact;");
        //var_dump($query);
        $data = array();
        $counter = 0;
        $i = 0;
        while($row = $query->fetch_row())
        {   
            $record = array(
                "ID" => $row[0],
                "NAME" => $row[1],
                "PHONE" => $row[2],
                "ADDRESS" => $row[3]
                );
        $data[] = $record;
        //$data[$i++] = "ID: {$row[0]} NAME: {$row[1]} PHONE: {$row[2]} ADDRESS: $row[3]";
        //$data .= "ID: {$row[0]} NAME: {$row[1]} PHONE: {$row[2]} ADDRESS: $row[3]";
        //$counter .= $counter;//var_dump($data);
        //$assoc = $query->fetch_all();
        //var_dump($assoc);
        //return $assoc;
        }
        //var_dump($data);

        return $data;

    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->dbCon->close();
    }

} //END OF dbClass

$dbClassConnection = new dbClass();

/*function displayRecords($recordData) {
//var_dump($recordData[0]);
}*/
//$name = $_POST['name'];
//$phone = $_POST['phone'];
//$address = $_POST['address'];
//$name = "AutoInput";
//$phone = "AutoInput";
//$address = "AutoInput";

//var_dump($dbClassConnection);
if ($_POST['name'] == "" || $_POST['phone'] == "" || $_POST['address'] == "") {

    $recordData = $dbClassConnection->grabRecords()
    echo json_encode($recordData);

    //echo json_encode("HELLO");
    //$recordData = $dbClassConnection->grabRecords();
    //echo json_encode("FIRST IF");
    //var_dump($recordData);
} else {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    $recordData = $dbClassConnection->saveDBRecord($name,$phone,$address);
    //$jsonData = displayRecords($recordData);
    //var_dump(json_encode($recordData);
    echo json_encode($recordData);
    //var_dump($jsonData);
    //echo json_encode("SECOND IF");
    //var_dump($recordData);
}

//$name = $_POST['name'];
//ar_dump($name;
//echo json_encode($_POST);

//IF SUBMIT TRUE
//saveDBRecord and grabRecords
//ELSE
//JUST GrabRecords
```

?>

Comment: So, if instead of using ajax you use a post method on your submit form, then works, or fails too??

Comment: If I move the $_POST['name'] variables and hardset them to values above the functions it seems that the database grab and save work fine.  I think it may have to do with my IF statement.

if ($_POST['name'] == "" || $_POST['phone'] == "" || $_POST['address'] == "")

Basically I am trying to check if the $_POST data has any actual data in it besides blank/NULL if so I just want it to grab records.  If it has data I want it to save to the database then grab.  

Is there a good way to check this?  The AjaxCall will always send formData since I'm only using one ajaxCall, so $_POST is always set.

Comment: If you made a console.log(formData) in your ajax call...its well formed, is it?

Comment: Everything looks like it comes out fine as JSON_ENCODE

Comment: [{"ID":"138","NAME":"","PHONE":"","ADDRESS":""},{"ID":"139","NAME":"","PHONE":"","ADDRESS":""}]

that is what comes out basically with more records.
I can make this work fine with hardcoded variables instead of $_POST.  Basically as a regular PHP script.

Comment: In the begin of your php script put this to see how the post array comes: var_dump( $_POST ) ;

Comment: I got the save record to work async again.  I believe it is just the $_POST if statement.  I believe the $_POST statement is = [] on first call then if i put in informatoin it seems to load fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30185/discussion-between-kmalik-and-robert-rozas)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the ajaxCall onLoad needed to serialize the formData as well and then the issue was with how I was handling the POST data for the IF statements.